# Import a csv file into Jupyter Notebook with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need help with the following:

I was trying to import a csv file into my Jupyter notebook but to no avail.

The code i used was:

> dfa = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')

And the following error message was given:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-164d461fc4d7> in <module>()
----> 1 dfa = pd.read_csv('Airpollution.csv')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    444 
    445     try:
--> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
    447     finally:
    448         parser.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1035 
-> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1037 
   1038         # May alter columns / col_dict

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1846     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1847         try:
-> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1849         except StopIteration:
   1850             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 11
```

I have checked that the files are opened from the same folder, and they are all stored in my Desktop.

I have pandas, matplotlib and seaborn installed. I have tried all ways (other solutions from Stackoverflow) but could not figure out why I am unable to import. Please enlighten me. Thank you!

-

@jpp:
[Another csv file was able to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro0eE.png)
it is odd as I tried to use another csv file and it worked. i am unable to load these files in.

i am using the following information:

```
 Subject: Environment 
 Topic : Air Quality and Climate 
" Title  : M890641 - Air Pollution Levels, Annual "
, , , , , , , , , ,
 Variables , 2007 , 2008 , 2009 , 2010 , 2011 , 2012 , 2013 , 2014 , 2015 , 2016 ,
 Sulphur Dioxide (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 12 , 11 , 9 , 11 , 10 , 13 , 14 , 12 , 12 , 13 ,
 Sulphur Dioxide (Maximum 24-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 84 , 80 , 93 , 104 , 80 , 98 , 75 , 83 , 75 , 61 ,
 Nitrogen Dioxide (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 22 , 22 , 22 , 23 , 25 , 25 , 25 , 24 , 22 , 26 ,
 Nitrogen Dioxide (Maximum 1-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 177 , 126 , 147 , 153 , 189 , 154 , 132 , 121 , 99 , 123 ,
 Particulate Matter (PM10) (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 27 , 25 , 29 , 26 , 27 , 29 , 31 , 30 , 37 , 26 ,
 Particulate Matter (PM10) (99th Percentile 24-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 53 , 49 , 59 , 76 , 55 , 57 , 215 , 75 , 186 , 61 ,
 Particulate Matter (PM2.5) (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 19 , 16 , 19 , 17 , 17 , 19 , 20 , 18 , 24 , 15 ,
 Particulate Matter (PM2.5) (99th Percentile 24-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 37 , 32 , 44 , 56 , 41 , 42 , 176 , 51 , 145 , 40 ,
 Carbon Monoxide (Maximum 8-hour Mean) (Milligram Per Cubic Metre) , 1.7 , 1.6 , 1.9 , 2.4 , 2 , 1.9 , 5.5 , 1.8 , 3.3 , 2.2 ,
 Carbon Monoxide (Maximum 1-hour Mean) (Milligram Per Cubic Metre) , 2.5 , 2.3 , 3.9 , 2.8 , 2.6 , 2.4 , 7.5 , 2.7 , 3.5 , 2.7 ,
 Ozone (Maximum 8-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cubic Metre) , 206 , 183 , 105 , 139 , 123 , 122 , 139 , 135 , 152 , 115 ,





SOURCE: NATIONAL ENVIRONMENT AGENCY




Generated by: SingStat Table Builder 
Date generated: 05/09/2018
Contact: info@singstat.gov.sg
```

and this:

```
 Subject: Death and Life Expectancy 
 Topic : Death and Life Expectancy 
" Title  : M810131 - Deaths By Broad Groups Of Causes, Annual "
, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,Number
 Variables , 1969 , 1970 , 1971 , 1972 , 1973 , 1974 , 1975 , 1976 , 1977 , 1978 , 1979 , 1980 , 1981 , 1982 , 1983 , 1984 , 1985 , 1986 , 1987 , 1988 , 1989 , 1990 , 1991 , 1992 , 1993 , 1994 , 1995 , 1996 , 1997 , 1998 , 1999 , 2000 , 2001 , 2002 , 2003 , 2004 , 2005 , 2006 , 2007 , 2008 , 2009 , 2010 , 2011 , 2012 , 2013 , 2014 , 2015 , 2016 , 2017 ,
 Total Deaths By Causes ," 10,224 "," 10,717 "," 11,329 "," 11,522 "," 11,920 "," 11,674 "," 11,447 "," 11,648 "," 11,955 "," 12,065 "," 12,468 "," 12,505 "," 12,863 "," 12,896 "," 13,321 "," 13,162 "," 13,348 "," 12,821 "," 13,173 "," 13,690 "," 14,069 "," 13,891 "," 13,876 "," 14,337 "," 14,461 "," 14,946 "," 15,569 "," 15,590 "," 15,305 "," 15,657 "," 15,516 "," 15,693 "," 15,367 "," 15,820 "," 16,036 "," 15,860 "," 16,215 "," 16,393 "," 17,140 "," 17,222 "," 17,101 "," 17,610 "," 18,027 "," 18,481 "," 18,938 "," 19,393 "," 19,862 "," 20,017 "," 20,905 ",
     Infective And Parasitic Diseases , 708 , 727 , 702 , 752 , 775 , 714 , 630 , 554 , 523 , 502 , 503 , 425 , 432 , 393 , 432 , 390 , 375 , 402 , 432 , 430 , 439 , 347 , 321 , 342 , 398 , 366 , 369 , 358 , 318 , 361 , 311 , 276 , 296 , 289 , 250 , 296 , 373 , 257 , 307 , 285 , 279 , 269 , 244 , 233 , 211 , 217 , 194 , 174 , 189 ,
         Tuberculosis , 419 , 458 , 439 , 489 , 450 , 472 , 420 , 358 , 340 , 318 , 331 , 240 , 221 , 207 , 224 , 163 , 177 , 177 , 186 , 168 , 132 , 113 , 104 , 101 , 115 , 101 , 118 , 132 , 115 , 128 , 107 , 101 , 104 , 92 , 79 , 79 , 67 , 66 , 85 , 83 , 75 , 77 , 68 , 65 , 51 , 60 , 41 , 41 , 32 ,
     Neoplasms ," 1,577 "," 1,633 "," 1,728 "," 1,821 "," 1,912 "," 2,002 "," 2,123 "," 2,278 "," 2,326 "," 2,415 "," 2,542 "," 2,623 "," 2,672 "," 2,729 "," 2,903 "," 2,817 "," 2,939 "," 2,921 "," 3,169 "," 3,233 "," 3,321 "," 3,314 "," 3,405 "," 3,497 "," 3,560 "," 3,785 "," 3,921 "," 4,034 "," 4,178 "," 4,091 "," 4,168 "," 4,278 "," 4,384 "," 4,465 "," 4,187 "," 4,353 "," 4,331 "," 4,722 "," 4,803 "," 5,081 "," 5,063 "," 5,078 "," 5,461 "," 5,651 "," 5,849 "," 5,790 "," 5,986 "," 5,993 "," 6,237 ",
         Malignant Neoplasms ," 1,533 "," 1,596 "," 1,688 "," 1,773 "," 1,863 "," 1,955 "," 2,083 "," 2,245 "," 2,286 "," 2,386 "," 2,488 "," 2,561 "," 2,616 "," 2,668 "," 2,858 "," 2,776 "," 2,893 "," 2,887 "," 3,131 "," 3,194 "," 3,283 "," 3,269 "," 3,361 "," 3,456 "," 3,531 "," 3,756 "," 3,898 "," 3,985 "," 4,128 "," 4,050 "," 4,134 "," 4,238 "," 4,339 "," 4,425 "," 4,146 "," 4,303 "," 4,289 "," 4,677 "," 4,745 "," 5,038 "," 5,010 "," 5,025 "," 5,411 "," 5,565 "," 5,775 "," 5,701 "," 5,903 "," 5,925 "," 6,077 ",
"     Endocrine, Nutritional And Metabolic Diseases ", 331 , 250 , 308 , 271 , 342 , 377 , 375 , 408 , 429 , 403 , 403 , 359 , 404 , 397 , 423 , 512 , 492 , 508 , 521 , 525 , 461 , 388 , 359 , 269 , 309 , 374 , 327 , 403 , 366 , 401 , 444 , 458 , 629 , 530 , 473 , 545 , 593 , 620 , 722 , 551 , 378 , 272 , 356 , 279 , 253 , 296 , 270 , 363 , 340 ,
         Diabetes , 184 , 134 , 212 , 207 , 247 , 257 , 259 , 334 , 377 , 334 , 347 , 319 , 368 , 361 , 373 , 469 , 464 , 479 , 492 , 501 , 419 , 332 , 320 , 238 , 264 , 334 , 271 , 320 , 282 , 308 , 350 , 355 , 512 , 425 , 373 , 474 , 510 , 536 , 609 , 463 , 290 , 182 , 299 , 268 , 247 , 277 , 250 , 343 , 321 ,
     Diseases Of The Blood And Blood-forming Organs , 71 , 51 , 60 , 50 , 61 , 60 , 52 , 32 , 50 , 45 , 41 , 31 , 42 , 33 , 33 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 35 , 35 , 48 , 50 , 40 , 33 , 34 , 24 , 37 , 37 , 44 , 35 , 50 , 54 , 52 , 44 , 39 , 33 , 40 , 36 , 31 , 46 , 30 , 41 , 41 , 20 , 14 , 23 , 10 , 14 , 17 ,
     Diseases Of The Nervous System And Sense Organs , 221 , 173 , 166 , 171 , 169 , 149 , 133 , 129 , 110 , 114 , 122 , 131 , 114 , 121 , 92 , 97 , 87 , 87 , 102 , 133 , 111 , 143 , 117 , 127 , 93 , 71 , 89 , 89 , 95 , 110 , 105 , 107 , 122 , 94 , 67 , 81 , 68 , 62 , 64 , 75 , 68 , 92 , 117 , 166 , 137 , 144 , 210 , 226 , 185 ,
     Diseases Of The Circulatory System ," 2,733 "," 2,899 "," 3,120 "," 2,999 "," 3,169 "," 3,295 "," 3,369 "," 3,798 "," 3,889 "," 3,983 "," 4,233 "," 4,305 "," 4,413 "," 4,430 "," 4,436 "," 4,637 "," 4,651 "," 4,482 "," 4,675 "," 4,847 "," 5,082 "," 5,152 "," 5,070 "," 5,270 "," 5,315 "," 5,460 "," 5,560 "," 5,896 "," 5,680 "," 5,711 "," 5,810 "," 5,749 "," 5,588 "," 5,401 "," 5,727 "," 5,423 "," 5,397 "," 5,441 "," 5,835 "," 5,794 "," 5,611 "," 5,807 "," 5,720 "," 5,747 "," 5,765 "," 5,987 "," 6,101 "," 6,107 "," 6,541 ",
         Heart And Hypertensive Diseases ," 1,761 "," 1,780 "," 1,925 "," 1,819 "," 1,967 "," 2,014 "," 2,000 "," 2,283 "," 2,426 "," 2,518 "," 2,752 "," 2,777 "," 2,892 "," 2,866 "," 2,911 "," 3,156 "," 3,129 "," 3,028 "," 3,251 "," 3,318 "," 3,416 "," 3,385 "," 3,234 "," 3,457 "," 3,552 "," 3,653 "," 3,742 "," 3,984 "," 3,943 "," 3,950 "," 4,061 "," 3,976 "," 4,075 "," 3,856 "," 4,067 "," 3,714 "," 3,656 "," 3,833 "," 4,197 "," 4,201 "," 4,081 "," 4,161 "," 3,920 "," 3,848 "," 3,914 "," 4,165 "," 4,534 "," 4,576 "," 4,970 ",
         Cerebrovascular Disease , 863 ," 1,038 "," 1,103 "," 1,080 "," 1,131 "," 1,213 "," 1,244 "," 1,427 "," 1,360 "," 1,382 "," 1,409 "," 1,447 "," 1,438 "," 1,469 "," 1,454 "," 1,413 "," 1,418 "," 1,355 "," 1,343 "," 1,414 "," 1,551 "," 1,666 "," 1,700 "," 1,697 "," 1,652 "," 1,692 "," 1,701 "," 1,805 "," 1,645 "," 1,633 "," 1,633 "," 1,625 "," 1,409 "," 1,393 "," 1,556 "," 1,562 "," 1,616 "," 1,462 "," 1,490 "," 1,435 "," 1,375 "," 1,472 "," 1,628 "," 1,714 "," 1,680 "," 1,620 "," 1,357 "," 1,317 "," 1,310 ",
     Diseases Of The Respiratory System ," 1,235 "," 1,473 "," 1,502 "," 1,653 "," 1,663 "," 1,631 "," 1,632 "," 1,651 "," 1,902 "," 1,724 "," 2,024 "," 1,965 "," 2,196 "," 2,257 "," 2,429 "," 2,096 "," 2,241 "," 1,974 "," 1,942 "," 2,110 "," 2,167 "," 2,112 "," 2,289 "," 2,522 "," 2,588 "," 2,564 "," 2,912 "," 2,534 "," 2,385 "," 2,579 "," 2,357 "," 2,505 "," 2,239 "," 2,763 "," 2,992 "," 2,851 "," 3,124 "," 2,913 "," 2,948 "," 2,989 "," 3,188 "," 3,434 "," 3,493 "," 3,708 "," 4,061 "," 4,232 "," 4,417 "," 4,440 "," 4,757 ",
         Pneumonia , 655 , 843 , 875 , 951 , 950 , 969 , 948 ," 1,010 "," 1,215 ", 942 ," 1,124 "," 1,129 "," 1,284 "," 1,375 "," 1,513 "," 1,204 "," 1,287 "," 1,082 ", 998 ," 1,039 "," 1,130 "," 1,191 "," 1,285 "," 1,420 "," 1,596 "," 1,670 "," 2,028 "," 1,693 "," 1,553 "," 1,780 "," 1,641 "," 1,794 "," 1,540 "," 2,079 "," 2,340 "," 2,232 "," 2,437 "," 2,244 "," 2,375 "," 2,387 "," 2,614 "," 2,766 "," 2,879 "," 3,096 "," 3,512 "," 3,680 "," 3,859 "," 3,855 "," 4,212 ",
     Diseases Of The Digestive System , 402 , 454 , 463 , 463 , 453 , 451 , 423 , 384 , 382 , 359 , 382 , 368 , 385 , 400 , 403 , 369 , 394 , 326 , 329 , 380 , 363 , 374 , 406 , 353 , 361 , 394 , 409 , 416 , 357 , 418 , 412 , 326 , 307 , 339 , 383 , 356 , 385 , 384 , 392 , 377 , 351 , 436 , 426 , 414 , 418 , 482 , 477 , 467 , 485 ,
     Diseases Of The Genito-urinary System , 234 , 239 , 252 , 279 , 275 , 320 , 311 , 281 , 324 , 381 , 349 , 366 , 366 , 319 , 375 , 405 , 319 , 343 , 393 , 380 , 370 , 346 , 369 , 362 , 371 , 444 , 483 , 444 , 399 , 494 , 470 , 486 , 487 , 594 , 587 , 641 , 634 , 637 , 739 , 753 , 861 , 893 , 918 , 934 , 967 , 951 , 928 , 913 , 925 ,
     Congenital Anomalies , 181 , 150 , 186 , 172 , 189 , 177 , 146 , 156 , 141 , 185 , 184 , 185 , 178 , 182 , 155 , 172 , 189 , 202 , 171 , 201 , 170 , 189 , 164 , 163 , 160 , 148 , 157 , 130 , 108 , 112 , 95 , 85 , 79 , 69 , 59 , 49 , 67 , 70 , 55 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 53 , 54 , 47 , 50 , 62 , 72 , 49 ,
         Congenital Anomalies Of Heart , 84 , 76 , 102 , 93 , 94 , 101 , 76 , 70 , 70 , 98 , 105 , 111 , 109 , 101 , 86 , 91 , 84 , 101 , 87 , 98 , 75 , 84 , 82 , 92 , 94 , 90 , 89 , 74 , 68 , 57 , 48 , 48 , 33 , 40 , 32 , 28 , 38 , 42 , 40 , 32 , 36 , 35 , 21 , 25 , 21 , 26 , 32 , 38 , 22 ,
     Certain Causes Of Perinatal Mortality , 460 , 463 , 455 , 502 , 477 , 322 , 254 , 221 , 247 , 239 , 261 , 227 , 208 , 215 , 149 , 151 , 147 , 128 , 128 , 127 , 135 , 123 , 89 , 82 , 76 , 68 , 51 , 64 , 61 , 62 , 52 , 48 , 24 , 52 , 41 , 22 , 39 , 43 , 32 , 39 , 49 , 34 , 49 , 44 , 43 , 42 , 30 , 36 , 39 ,
"     Accidents, Poisonings And Violence ", 811 , 836 , 968 , 982 , 995 , 894 , 887 , 890 , 914 ," 1,057 ", 876 , 899 , 938 , 966 ," 1,085 "," 1,095 "," 1,082 "," 1,025 ", 931 , 958 ," 1,042 "," 1,008 "," 1,074 "," 1,127 "," 1,066 "," 1,122 "," 1,113 "," 1,040 "," 1,187 "," 1,110 "," 1,066 "," 1,133 "," 1,036 "," 1,053 "," 1,062 "," 1,028 "," 1,017 "," 1,027 "," 1,036 "," 1,006 ", 978 , 973 , 989 ," 1,030 ", 933 , 909 , 895 , 890 , 840 ,
         Suicides , 188 , 185 , 230 , 235 , 240 , 229 , 252 , 257 , 224 , 266 , 249 , 271 , 191 , 239 , 267 , 211 , 327 , 329 , 302 , 367 , 395 , 354 , 319 , 298 , 296 , 347 , 401 , 271 , 346 , 371 , 309 , 348 , 357 , 361 , 346 , 381 , 405 , 419 , 374 , 364 , 401 , 353 , 361 , 467 , 422 , 415 , 409 , 429 , 361 ,
         Transport Accidents , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , na , 199 , 232 , 226 , 201 , 208 , 207 , 192 , 176 , 183 , 168 , 164 , 141 ,
     Other Diseases And Causes ," 1,260 "," 1,369 "," 1,419 "," 1,407 "," 1,440 "," 1,282 "," 1,112 ", 866 , 718 , 658 , 548 , 621 , 515 , 454 , 406 , 393 , 403 , 393 , 345 , 331 , 360 , 345 , 173 , 190 , 130 , 126 , 141 , 145 , 127 , 173 , 176 , 188 , 124 , 127 , 167 , 182 , 147 , 181 , 176 , 166 , 185 , 221 , 160 , 201 , 240 , 270 , 282 , 322 , 301 ,



"Deaths prior to 1979 are classified according to the eighth (1965) revision of the International Classification of Diseases.  Deaths from 1979 to 2011 are classified according to the ninth (1975) revision.  From 2012, deaths are classified according to the tenth revision."

SOURCE: REGISTRY OF BIRTHS AND DEATHS




Generated by: SingStat Table Builder 
Date generated: 05/09/2018
Contact: info@singstat.gov.sg
```

I'm not quite sure if it has something to do with the file or the settings in my mac.. thank you!

Comment: Hi @jpp, understood. I'll be updating my question with the data that I have used. Thank you!

Comment: could you post three lines from your csv file?

Comment: first 14 rows will be enough as its written in the error message

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti I have posted the csv file into my question. It's not a huge file, or rather they are both not huge files..

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo hi! is this because there are too many rows in the csv file?

Comment: no thats not the reason, its because during the process of tokenization the parser is not able to understand some token, we have to identify in which row

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo Sorry, as I'm still a beginner in python, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could it be due to some error in the CSV file? Thank you so much for helping with this. I have tried other methods but they all do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the parameters available to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). For example, you can specify separators and skip rows. You have an empty column at the end and garbage at the bottom, but this can be handled *after* reading your file.

For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=' *, *', skiprows=4, engine='python')\
       .dropna(subset=['2007'])\
       .iloc[:, :-1]

print(df)

                                            Variables   2007   2008   2009  \
0   Sulphur Dioxide (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per C...   12.0   11.0    9.0   
1   Sulphur Dioxide (Maximum 24-hour Mean) (Microg...   84.0   80.0   93.0   
2   Nitrogen Dioxide (Annual Mean) (Microgram Per ...   22.0   22.0   22.0   
3   Nitrogen Dioxide (Maximum 1-hour Mean) (Microg...  177.0  126.0  147.0   
4   Particulate Matter (PM10) (Annual Mean) (Micro...   27.0   25.0   29.0   
5   Particulate Matter (PM10) (99th Percentile 24-...   53.0   49.0   59.0   
6   Particulate Matter (PM2.5) (Annual Mean) (Micr...   19.0   16.0   19.0   
7   Particulate Matter (PM2.5) (99th Percentile 24...   37.0   32.0   44.0   
8   Carbon Monoxide (Maximum 8-hour Mean) (Milligr...    1.7    1.6    1.9   
9   Carbon Monoxide (Maximum 1-hour Mean) (Milligr...    2.5    2.3    3.9   
10  Ozone (Maximum 8-hour Mean) (Microgram Per Cub...  206.0  183.0  105.0   

     2010   2011   2012   2013   2014   2015   2016  
0    11.0   10.0   13.0   14.0   12.0   12.0   13.0  
1   104.0   80.0   98.0   75.0   83.0   75.0   61.0  
2    23.0   25.0   25.0   25.0   24.0   22.0   26.0  
3   153.0  189.0  154.0  132.0  121.0   99.0  123.0  
4    26.0   27.0   29.0   31.0   30.0   37.0   26.0  
5    76.0   55.0   57.0  215.0   75.0  186.0   61.0  
6    17.0   17.0   19.0   20.0   18.0   24.0   15.0  
7    56.0   41.0   42.0  176.0   51.0  145.0   40.0  
8     2.4    2.0    1.9    5.5    1.8    3.3    2.2  
9     2.8    2.6    2.4    7.5    2.7    3.5    2.7  
10  139.0  123.0  122.0  139.0  135.0  152.0  115.0
```

Comment: thats what i meant @booyabooya

Comment: @jpp thank you for your kind assistance! i tried exploring on my own and edited the same dataset in excel and removed the information at the top and bottom, and it seemed to work! but i don't think we are allowed to touch the dataset haha. nevertheless thank you for teaching me something new today!

Comment: @booyabooya, Just to be clear, I did not edit any of your data before testing my solution. As per my description this is handled by `read_csv` and subsequent methods.

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo thank you so much as well! as mentioned in my comment before, i experimented with cleaning up the dataset and it seemed to work. thank you so much for teaching me something new today!

Comment: @booyabooya, If this (or another) solution solves your problem feel free to accept (green tick on left) so other users know.

Comment: @booyabooya accept the answer if it solves your questions and problem.

Comment: @jpp Understood! I might need some help in understanding the codes. I don't quite get >> dropna(subset=['2007']) << and >>    .iloc[:, :-1] <<. What are they supposed to do? thank you!

Comment: `dropna` with `subset` specified as here means drop all rows where data in column `'2007'` is null (i.e. all the garbage at the bottom). `iloc[:, :-1]` means select all rows and all columns except the very last one (since for some reason each line in your file ends with `,`).

Comment: @jpp ah, got it! thank you for patiently explaining these to me. it helps a lot. :)

Comment: also could use `usecols=range(11)` to ignore that last `,` column. Again `pd.read_csv` can basically do it all :D

Comment: @ALollz, Agreed, I just fear this comma at the end thing is systematic rather than only occurring when you have 11 columns. But, yes, that would definitely be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip bad lines (mismatched number of fields):

```
dfa = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv',error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: hi, @peyman thanks for answering to my question! I shall give this a try as well. thank you!

Comment: i tried it in my codes and it tells me about the errors within the code. how should i eliminate these mismatched fields?

Comment: those will be eliminated automatically if you set `error_bad_lines=False`. If you don't want to see the error lines being printed out then you can pass this parameter as well: `warn_bad_lines=False`